# Python - How do I compute interactive spatial autocorrelation (Moran I) using PySAL?

Tags: python, spatial, pysal

I have a points table `my_table` my in PostgreSQL database with `geometry` column and other attributes. I have some sample data of `my_table` like follows (attributes of `my_table`).

```
id  val1
1   72.54513286
2   73.67371014
3   74.204424
4   73.76017279
5   77.7912762
6   77.78789496
7   65.51822878
8   65.5182287
9   74.65885753
10  74.65885753
11  61.18084042
12  60.75827621
13  64.27716322
14  63.69432836
15  75.790405
16  60.95270235
17  79.12399503
18  62.9667706
19  78.1265630
```

Using Python [PySAL](http://pysal.github.io/index.html) package, I would like to analyse that whether values in column `val1` are sptially autocorrelated (Moran I) (by interatively plotting them). My expected output of interactive spatial autocorrelation could be like (image source, [here](http://pysal.github.io/index.html)):

[image: expected_output]

I am new to Python. Can someone suggest me how to do this using PySAL?

Answer (score 6):

I have been using PySAL to compute Moran's I in my projects, and I find it relatively straightforward.

To compute Moran's I, you need two objects:

1. A weight matrix that represents the degree of relationship between the cells for which you want to verify autocorrelation.
2. The data itself.

In my projects, the cells I examine for autocorrelation are arranged like a mosaic. Therefore, I compute the weight matrix using the Contiguity Based Weights method, which is quite effective.

Here's an example of how to compute Moran's I for a two-dimensional data matrix, Z:

```
 from libpysal.weights import lat2W
 from esda.moran import Moran
 import numpy as np

 # Use your matrix here, instead of this random one
 Z = np.random.rand(200,150)

 # Create the matrix of weigthts 
 w = lat2W(Z.shape[0], Z.shape[1])

 # Create the pysal Moran object 
 mi = Moran(Z, w)

 # Verify Moran's I results 
 print(mi.I) 
 print(mi.p_norm)
```

I suggest starting with a random matrix, Z. In this instance, the outcome of Moran's I should approximate 0, serving as an effective test. Once you've verified it works with the random Z data, you can then substitute in your actual data.

Comment: What I'm seeing now is `'pysal' has no attribute 'lat2W'` . the API may have changed. 
```from libpysal.weights import lat2W
from esda.moran import Moran
import numpy as np

Z = np.array([[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]])

# Create the matrix of weigthts
w = lat2W(Z.shape[0], Z.shape[1])

# Crate the pysal Moran object
mi = Moran(Z, w)

# Verify Moran's I results
print(mi.I)
print(mi.p_norm)```

Comment: What if I want to use a custom w matrix of weights? How do I create that? It needs to be a libpysal.weights.weights object to function...

EDIT: forget it, found the answer already, I have to build a w object with libpysal.weights.W

Answer (score -3):

I guess you mean correlated not auto-correlated?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation

Can you use Pandas instead?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html

[Pandas correlate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html)

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pandas.read_csv("C:\\Users\\4Sight\\Desktop\\test.csv", sep=" +", usecols=("val1", "val2"))

print data

print data.columns.values

print data["val1"].corr(data["val2"])

plt.figure()
data.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You get my upvote. Unforturnately, not exactly I am looking for. Please see the edit I have added more details to make things clear. My aim is to get my expected outcome using Python. The column values are attributes of a shapefile in my Postgres db thus I want to investigate whether they are spatial auto-correlated. Please see: http://gisgeography.com/spatial-autocorrelation-moran-i-gis/

Comment: Pandas is a Python library. Looks like that link has the information you need. You can read in the CSV into  [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) and then call the functions in that guide.

Comment: This post should be deleted. The question is about spatial autocorrelation.